# Python subprocess with vars

Tags: python, unix, awk, terminal, subprocess

My Problem:

As a command in Terminal.app `/path/to/bin sth vars="bla blub moep"` works.

e.g.: `$ gawk -f sth.awk vars="FNAME DATE" aFile.bin`

But if I run it inside a python script, no output is given.

```
import subprocess as s
names = "bla blub moep"
cmd = ['/path/to/bin', 'sth', 'vars="'+names+'"']
print s.check_output(cmd, stdout=s.PIPE)
```

If I remove `vars=""`, it works but without full functionality.
Escaping the `"` character, doesn´t change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bash` command and your `python` command are different in a subtle but likely important way.  The difference is that the python command passes literal double-quote characters to `awk` but the `bash` command does not.  The solution is to remove the excess double-quotes from the python script.

#### Example

To be clear, let's consider the following sample files:

```
$ cat file
we have a match.
$ cat sth.awk
/match/{print "my vars=",vars}
```

Now, run the bash command:

```
$ awk -f sth.awk -v vars="bla blub moep" file
my vars= bla blub moep
```

Note that there are *no* double quotes in the output.

Now, lets run this python code:

```
import subprocess as s
names = "bla blub moep"
cmd = ['awk', '-f', 'sth.awk', 'vars="' + names + '"', 'file']
print s.check_output(cmd)
```

This results in:

```
my vars= "bla blub moep"
```

Note the unwanted double-quotes.

Now, let's try this again without the excess double-quotes:

```
import subprocess as s
names = "bla blub moep"
cmd = ['awk', '-f', 'sth.awk', 'vars=' + names, 'file']
print s.check_output(cmd)
```

This produces the output:

```
my vars= bla blub moep
```

Note that, having removed the double-quotes, this output is now the same as the bash output.  This will give you the same results that the `bash` command would.

#### Documentation

`bash` performs many operations on a command line before actually calling the command.  These include familiar ones like variable substitution.  The last step before calling the command is quote removal.  From `man bash`

> **Quote Removal**
>   After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters \, ', and " that did not result from one of the above
>   expansions are removed.

Because of this, `awk` never sees the double-quotes even though they are on the `bash` command line above.